# The method 'XXX' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I am a real newbie of flutter and would like to seek your help to solve the following problem:

I want to write the current time to a file but following error is shown:

======= Exception caught by widgets library =====================

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The method 'writeStartTimeString' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: writeStartTimeString("1629015208721")

Here is my code:

```
**startTimeStorage.dart**

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class StartTimeStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    print('$path/startTime.txt');
    return File('$path/startTime.txt');
  }

  Future<String> readStartTimeString() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      final contents = await file.readAsString();
      print('reading');
      print(contents);
      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return ''
      return '';
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeStartTimeString(String startTimeString) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    print('writing');
    print(startTimeString);
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString(startTimeString);
  }
}
```

```
**main File:**

class ParkingTimerScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  StartTimeStorage startTimeStorage;

  _ParkingTimerScreen createState() => _ParkingTimerScreen();
}

class _ParkingTimerScreen extends State<ParkingTimerScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var _timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print('printing _timestamp:$_timestamp');

    //Writing to file, ***where error appears.***
    widget.startTimeStorage.writeStartTimeString(_timestamp.toString());


    //Reading from file and store the value to startTimeString
    widget.startTimeStorage.readStartTimeString().then((String value) {
      startTimeString = value;
    });

//...other code.....
//.....

}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `startTimeStorage`. At least not in the code shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise the StartTimeStorage variable in ParkingTimeScreen Class.

```
class ParkingTimerScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  StartTimeStorage startTimeStorage = StartTimeStorage();

  _ParkingTimerScreen createState() => _ParkingTimerScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use an initializer

in your main file `ParkingTimerScreen` widget get the `startTimeStorage`
but you did not initialize it and the application throws that error

because `startTimeStorage` is null and `readStartTimeString` call on a null variable

```
class ParkingTimerScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  StartTimeStorage startTimeStorage;
  ParkingTimerScreen({required this.startTimeStorage});

  _ParkingTimerScreen createState() => _ParkingTimerScreen();
}
```